# How to convert an array in a string to an array on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'd like to convert an string containing an array to an array.

**Here's the string :**

```
var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";
```

**Here's the result I want (not a string anymore) :**

```
var colorsArray = ['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3'];
```

The double quotes will always be on the beginning and on the end, so I found this code from another post but my string still remains as string...

> colors.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1');

How can I achieve this and what's the best practice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex

```js
var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']";

console.log(colors.match(/#....../g))
console.log(colors.match(/#[a-f0-9]{6}/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the String.match

```
colors.match(/(#[a-f0-9]{6})/g)
```

will return an array of colours

Answer (score 0):

Replace single qoutes with double and use `JSON.parse`

```
var colorsArray = JSON.parse(colors.replace(/'/g,'"'))
```

Comment: @charlietfl You can open console and run this code. After replacing single quotes with double it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you trust the input is safe you can use `eval()`

```js
var colors = "['#e6f0ff', '#000a1a' ,'#ffe680', '#ffcc00', '#ffd9b3']",
  colorsArray = eval(colors);

console.log('colorsArray is array = ', Array.isArray(colorsArray))
```